# Avoid $(document).click for certain textfiels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 2 text fields and a button and also a `$(document).click` function to trigger `showItems()` function.

My question is how can I avoid `showItems()` from been triggered if the user is currently typing anything into those 2 text fields?

```
<input type="text" id="tf1">
<input type="text" id="tf2">
<button id="bt1">Preference</button>
```

```js
$(document).click(function(){
    if (typeof showItems() == "function") { 
       showItems();
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the click passed through `#tf1` or `#tf2`:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#tf1, #tf2").length) {
      return;
    }
    if (typeof showItems == "function") {
        showItems();
    }
});
```

**Example**:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#tf1, #tf2").length) {
      return;
    }
    $("<p>click</p>").appendTo(document.body);        
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tf1">
<input type="text" id="tf2">
<button id="bt1">Preference</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that when checking the type of `showItems`, you **don't** want the `()` on it, that will *call* it and check the type of what it returns. I've removed the `()` in the first code block above.

Comment: @Becky: Just updated, I don't know why I didn't use `"#tf1, #tf2"` in the first place.

Comment: Can `#bt1` be included as well?

Comment: @Becky: Yup, you can add any relevant selector to the group.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be this:

```
<input type="text" id="tf1" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
```

The click events bubble up the DOM from the element that was clicked. This way you stop it from bubbling up and it never reaches the document root.

Answer (score 1):

> [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  if (typeof showItems == "function") {
    showItems();
  }
});

function showItems() {
  console.log('Here!');
}
$('#tf1,#tf2').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tf1">
<input type="text" id="tf2">
<button id="bt1">Preference</button>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f3skkg9d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

using `.click()` function without a target is never a good idea. rather use the button as a target for your click event for example:

```
<input type="text" id="tf1">
<input type="text" id="tf2">
<button id="bt1">Preference</button>

$("#bt1").click(function(){
    if (typeof showItems() == "function") { 
       showItems();
    }        
});
```

but i am not sure when you want your click-event to actually fire.